# fetch multiple url in a object react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this object, i want to fecth all url.

```
Object {
  "Info": "/api/2",
  "Logo": "/api/2/Logo",
  "Photo": "/api/2/photo",
}
```

I want to store the response in a state, like in the example below, I can't know the keys of the object, but no matter what key is the response is organized with that key

```
Data
[
   "Info": 
       ['API RESULTS'],
   "Logo": 
       ['API RESULTS'],
   "Photo": 
       ['API RESULTS']
]
```

I made the promise like this

```
     await Promise.all(Object.values(RequestURL).map(Url => 
     {
         fetch(`${this.state.URL}${Url}`)
         .then(Res => Res.json())
         .then(Res => this.setState({Data: [...this.state.Data, Res.Data] }))
         .catch(Err => this.setState({ IsLoading: false, IsError: true}))
      }))
```

but I don't have the result in the format I want because I only store the data in an array, not an object with the key-value

```
this.setState({Data: [...this.state.Data, Res.Data] }))
```

the response I got is

```
Array [
  Array [
    Object {
        "API_DATA"
    }
```

and i want something like this

```
Array [
  Info: [
    Object {
        "API_DATA"
    }
  Logo: [
    Object {
        "API_DATA"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) you could pass both the key and the value of each object entry into the `map` function. Then wait for the response to finish and return a new array with the key and the returned data as a pair.

In the `map` loop don't forget to return the result of the request, otherwise there is nothing to use `Promise.all()` on.

After all responses are in you can turn this array of arrays back into an object with [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), reversing the effect.

To demonstrate how it works I've made an example with the [Star Wars API](https://swapi.dev/) to perform dummy requests.

```js
const endpoints = {
  "Info": "people/1/",
  "Logo": "planets/2/",
  "Photo": "starships/9/",
};

const responses = Object.entries(endpoints).map(async ([ key, url ]) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/${url}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return [ key, data ];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

Promise.all(responses)
  .then(results => Object.fromEntries(results))
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: thanks men, in my case i store the result in the state like this .then(Res => this.setState({Data: Res}));

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop slightly to use `Object.keys` instead of `Object.values` so that you can get both the keys and values.

Simplified version:

```js
const obj = {
  Info: "/api/2",
  Logo: "/api/2/Logo",
  Photo: "/api/2/photo",
}

Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  console.log('key', key);
  console.log('value', obj[key]);
})
```

Then set your state with a dynamic property like this:

```js
this.setState({ [key]: yourData })
```